# Problem with creating XML drawable

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I’m trying to create a roll over affect for my `ImageButton`s in my application I’ve been following the guide on the android developer’s site here’s the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

I’ve been trying to create the required XML drawable file which will change the image if it’s clicked but I’m unsure what type of xml file to create, whether it be animation, layout, value etc. When I go to create the file it forces you to select the type of file which stops you creating the xml in the drawable folder.

Does anyone know what typesof xml file I need to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case just don't select `Android XML File` in that list. Select `Other` and in the following list select `XML File` from the XML section. Give it an appropriate name and then just define what you need to define.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply that’s solved it, seems so obvious now. 
Cheers  mate